# How to change class and count number of likes when click on like button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 and I'd like to make like button but I did not reach to change class of button and change count of likes when user click on like button.

This the typescript code:

```
getData() {
    this.http.get(Globals.baseUrl + 'articles').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.results = data;
    });
}

likeClick(url, i) {
this.http.get(url).subscribe(
    data => {
    },
    (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Client-side error occured.');
        }
    }
  );
}
```

and this is the html code:

If user has already liked this article so **span** will have blue color which is unlike class and if he has no like so the **span** will have black color which is like class and **this works fine** only the first time when page is opened.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let result of results.articles; let i = index">
// .......
<ion-row>
    <ion-col>
        <button ion-button color="primary" clear small icon-start
            (click)="likeClick(result?._links.create_like.href, index)">
   <span [ngClass]="{'unlike': result?.userHasLike == true, 'like': result?.userHasLike == false}">Like&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <ion-icon name='thumbs-up'></ion-icon>{{result?.nbLikes }}</span>
        </button>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: whats the problem ?You said its working ! what do want to achieve exactly ?

Comment: `index` in function call of `(click)` should probably be `i`.

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya , no , class and count of likes works fine only when loading and display data the first time when user open the page but not woks when click on button like

Comment: @Arg0n, yes I will correct it.  do you have any solution please ?

Comment: You need to update the item manually in the success callback of the http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this as a new answer because it is a totally different solution from the old answer. As @hous suggested reloading the whole data couldn't be too efficient, therefore why not set it manually to the result:-

```
getData() {
    this.http.get(Globals.baseUrl + 'articles').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.results = data;
    });
}

//why is i there when it is never used?
likeClick(url, result) {
this.http.get(url).map (data => data.json()).subscribe(
    data => {

         if (result) {
              //the exact syntax I am not sure about, but, I would guess the response should contain some data indicating whether the userHasLike that could be used to initialize the current result
              result.userHasLike = data.userHasLike;
         }
    },
    (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Client-side error occured.');
        }
    }
  );
}
```

then, in the template, we could initialize it to result instead of i:-

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let result of results.articles; let i = index">
// .......
<ion-row>
    <ion-col>
        <button ion-button color="primary" clear small icon-start
            (click)="likeClick(result?._links.create_like.href, result)">
   <span [ngClass]="{'unlike': result?.userHasLike == true, 'like': result?.userHasLike == false}">Like&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <ion-icon name='thumbs-up'></ion-icon>{{result?.nbLikes }}</span>
        </button>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

so as he said @Raef Kandil with some modifications:

this is th function:

```
likeClick(url, index, result) {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
        data => {
            if (result.userHasLike == false){
                result.userHasLike = true;
                result.nbLikes++;
            }
            else{
                result.userHasLike = false;
                result.nbLikes--;
            }
        },
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Client-side error occured.');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

and this is the button :

```
<button ion-button color="primary" clear small icon-start
     (click)="likeClick(result?._links.create_like.href, i, result)">
     <span [ngClass]="{'unlike': result?.userHasLike == true, 'like': result?.userHasLike == false}">J'aime&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <ion-icon name='thumbs-up'></ion-icon>{{result?.nbLikes }}</span>
            </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is I understand it, when the user clicks on the like icon, the result doesn't get updated automatically on the screen and a refresh is required, then as @ArgOn suggested, you might have to need to update the results on successful callback. This could work.

```
getData() {
    this.http.get(Globals.baseUrl + 'articles').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.results = data;
    });
}

likeClick(url, i) {
this.http.get(url).subscribe(
    data => {
         this.getData();
    },
    (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Client-side error occured.');
        }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: this is correct, this couldn't be too efficient, did you try using [(ngModel)] and link it to some form of input?